# Wordpress: Imagem colocada no header.php some nas páginas internas

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

No `header.php` eu coloco por exemplo

```
<img src="wp-content/themes/meu_tema/asserts/imagens/logo.png" title=" />
```

Na página inicial funciona, mas nas internas não funciona.

Como contornar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando uma URL relativa, então quando você sai da página inicial,`wp-content/themes/meu_tema/asserts/imagens/logo.png` está sendo adicionado à URL da página em que você está, por isso não funciona.

A forma rápida (e suja) de resolver é adicionar uma `/` ao início da URL:

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/meu_tema/asserts/imagens/logo.png" title=" />
```

A forma mais correta é usar as funções [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) ou [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/), assim:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri(). '/asserts/imagens/logo.png' ); ?>" title="" />
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/asserts/imagens/logo.png' ); ?>" title="" />
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas ele não concatena com `/asserts/imagens/logo.png` e o output é: `<img src="http://www.meusite.com.br/wp-content/themes/meu_tema" title="Meu Site" alt="Meu Site">`, o que pode ser?

Comment: Opa, falha minha. Troquei as vírgulas por pontos ali e agora deve funcionar.

Comment: Ricardo, agora funcionou. E também "reinando" antes de ver sua resposta, consegui assim também: `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/asserts/imagens/logo.png"  title="<?php bloginfo('name') ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name') ?>" />`. A seu código é mais elegante. obrigado.